# How can I set an SKCameraNode's position x and y relative to a node?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm setting up my camera node programatically. My goal is to have the camera follow the player node's x axis, but have the y axis of the camera higher than "player.position.y", something like "player.position.y + 300".

I found this after googling a while about this issue:

cam.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y + 500)

I put this in didMove(to:) along with the setup of the camera:

```
cam = SKCameraNode() //initialize and assign an instance of SKCameraNode to the cam variable.
    self.camera = cam //set the scene's camera to reference cam
    //cam.setScale(1.3)

cam.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y + 500)
    addChild(cam) //have cam be a child
```

I've tried putting it before and after the add child(cam) line, but the cam.position line had no effect.

I've tried both setting my camera up as a child of the player node and the scene, but with either method I can get the camera to follow the player but I can't figure out how to manipulate the X and Y separately. The only way Ive been able to affect the cameras position is using "set scale" but thats more of a global zoom in/out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The first part of the answer is all I needed:

```
cam = SKCameraNode()
player.addChild(cam)
cam.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:500)
self.camera = cam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make camera a child of player, then set the relative position to +500, so that you never have to worry about setting the camera x position again

```
cam = SKCameraNode()
player.addChild(cam)
cam.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:500)
self.camera = cam
```

Then on your end update, set your camera y based on what you need:

```
let cam = player.childNode[0] as! SKCameraNode //Do whatever you need to do to find the camera
cam.position.y = 500 - player.position.y //This way if the player goes up 1 point, the camera moves down one point thus keeping it on the same spot
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! this is almost perfect! your code works as intended but there is a side effect.

Comment: what side effect?

Comment: Thanks for the response! this is almost perfect! your code works as intended but there is a side effect. When I apply a jump to my player (applyImpulse) as the player jumps the entire scene seems to sluggishly drift up following the player until the player hits the ground again.

Comment: the y should not move at all,  are you applying thas on your didFinishUpdate...didEndUpdate (can't remember the name)

Comment: oh I am assuming player starts at 0 on y,  if the ground is not at 0, then you need to factor that in as well

Comment: I had to comment this line out:  //let cam = player.childNode[0] as! SKCameraNod because i didn't know what to do with it, but also put everything else you decried into "override func update(_ currenTime: TimeInterval)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147947/discussion-between-genericguy25-and-knight0fdragon).